# Google docs/sheets won't show

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

My Google docs and sheets won't show up. However, my Google forms will and I can get on the drive, admin, etc. This is only happening on one computer, so must be in settings. Other computers work and also on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** - Verify that you're logged in to the right google account (top right corner on desktop)

**Step 2** - Try accessing google docs or sheets in incognito mode or use a different browser

**Step 3** - If step 2 worked, clear cookies+chache and try again.